# Generating images of 3D array from any point of view

Tags: java, c++, math, 3d, d3dimage

I have a 3D array representing a 3D object (x,y,z). The values stored in the array are RGB colors. Is it possible to generate an image of the object from any given point of view?

Comment: You mean like 3D model? You can use OpenGL or DirectX to do that. AFAIK C++ does not have anything in standard for 3D rendering.

Comment: Daniel, you are right, like 3D model. I want to rotate the object and display it on the screen. I'm looking for an abstract implementation without using OpenGL or other big hammers.

Comment: Is OpenGL a big hammer? Huh, so you can write a program visualizer by yourself, but it will be neither hammer nor mallet. It will be a bulldozer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is certainly possible. The keywords here are transformation and projection, basically you define a point for every (3D) Pixel inside your array. Then you multiply all the points with a bunch of matrices and get a 2-dimensional result.

Here is an article about how OpenGL does it's transformations:
http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html

You could mimic the whole pipeline in C++ to produce a bitmap on your CPU or use OpenGL directly which would be a thousand times faster. When using OpenGL you could also view your model in realtime from all sides, but that would essentially be a full 3D-Application.

Comment: This is very helpful. I'm trying to avoid OpenGL because I need to show how the projection works since the project is intended for educational purposes.

Comment: Don't be afraid of the formulas, the matrices aren't that complicated, only the derivation of them ;)

Comment: It would be much easier if there was example code.

Comment: I found this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/239174-3d-perspective-projection/  but still not clear